# Dynamically creating an HTML link that passes a list to a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html, list, parameters, hyperlink

I have an HTML link that calls a JavaScript function that in turn makes a NEW link. This new link calls the same JS function when clicked, making another link etc. The function also creates a new `div` where the next link is added.

```js
function displayChildren(displayLocation, myList) {
        innerHtml = "";
        for (item in myList) {
            name = myList[item];
            newDisplayLocation = displayLocation + "/" + name;
            innerHtml += "<a href='#' onclick='displayChildren(\"" + newDisplayLocation + "\", " + myList + ");'>" + name + "</a>";
            innerHtml += "<div id='" + newDisplayLocation + "'></div>";
        }
        document.getElementById(displayLocation).innerHTML = innerHtml;
    }
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="displayChildren('{{myList.0}}', {{myList.1}})">{{myList.0}}</a><br />
<div id="{{myList.0}}"></div>
```

However, I want to pass this JS function a list as a parameter. The first HTML link made is not dynamically created and therefore can pass that list easily, but subsequent links will not give the JS function the list. The `onclick` tag will call the JS function and pass other parameters fine, but lists are turned into a string.

So the list `[["apple", []]]` will turn into `apple,`. This makes sense because I am putting this entire `<a>` tag into a string. But I still need that link to pass a list, or just in some way get this JS function a list. Any ideas how to do this?

Additional Information:

- I am using this to create a tree structure that will show all of a node's
  children when clicked.
- The list is changed each time it is passed to the JS function. It actually passes the list of the node's children.
- The page is not refreshing.

Comment: Have you tried to iterate through the list and add the curly braces + list item to a string manually. Then concatenate the <a with the constructed string instead of the list itself.

Comment: btw, your provided snippet throws a syntax error, it does not like the {

Comment: That's a good idea. While that is a solution though, it's one that I would rather avoid. It seems bulky, and then when the next JS function is called I would have to parse that string into a list again somehow.

Comment: Yes, that snippet does throw an error it seems. The {{x}} is Jinja, and just dictates a variable coming from my code-behind.